# Oracle time stamp in YYYYmmddHHMMSS format

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have time stamp in oracle db in following format (6/23/2017 12:00:00.000000 AM).

I need to convert it into `YYYYmmddHHMMSS` format.
I have tried to convert using

```
`to_char(time,"YYYYmmddHHMMSS")`
```

but it is giving like `20170623120600`. Instead of minutes it is giving months.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should give `MI` for minutes. so your conversion will go like this

```
to_char(time,'YYYYmmddHHMISS')`
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `MI` instead of `mm` to mention minutes, [oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) is your friend

Answer (score 2):

You need to first convert string to TimeStamp then convert it to your respective format.
You can try as below:

```
Select  
      To_Char(  
             To_TimeStamp('6/23/2017 12:00:00.000000 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF AM'),  
      'YYYYmmddHHMISS')  
from dual;
```

Comment: It appears to be stored as a timestamp coluln, not as a string, so the extra conversions aren't needed, or always safe. It's just being displayed with the session's NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT by default.

Answer (score 2):

> I have time stamp in oracle db in following format

No, there is not format for datetime when it is stored in the database. The format you see is only for display.

> Instead of minutes it is giving months.

It is obvious because you have used `MM` instead of `MI`.

- MM gives you the month number
- MI gives you the minutes in the time pportion

so, use:

```
to_char(time,YYYYMMDDHHMISS)
```

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDDHHMISS') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDAT
--------------
20150415050759

SQL>
```